# <a> not trigering my .js

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML code (using jquery 2.1.1 and bootstrap)

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
               <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title" >
                     <a value="Scroll" id="scroll" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                     Documentos de Recolha de Dados
                     </a>
                  </h4>
               </div>
               <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                     <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="docs/recdados/chk_act_dados.pdf"><img src="img/doc-pdf.png" alt="Download" class="img-rounded"><p>Lista de Documentos Necessários &#40;316KB&#41;</p></a></div>
                     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="docs/recdados/siie_colheita_de_dados_358.pdf"><img src="img/doc-pdf.png" alt="Download" class="img-rounded"><p>Recolha Dados SIIE &#40;221KB&#41;</p></a></div>
                     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="docs/recdados/Admissao_Ficha_de_saude.pdf"><img src="img/doc-pdf.png" alt="Download" class="img-rounded"><p>Ficha de Sa&uacute;de &#40;850KB&#41;</p></a></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
               <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a value="Scroll" id="scroll" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                  Regulamentos e Estatutos do CNE
                  </a>
               </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="docs/estatutos__do_cne.pdf"><img src="img/doc-pdf.png" alt="Download" class="img-rounded"><p>Estatutos do CNE &#40;113KB&#41;</p></a></div>
                     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="docs/regulamento_geral_do_cne.pdf"><img src="img/doc-pdf.png" alt="Download" class="img-rounded"><p>Regulamento Geral CNE &#40;592KB&#41;</p></a></div>
                     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="docs/regulamento_uniformes_do_cne.pdf"><img src="img/doc-pdf.png" alt="Download" class="img-rounded"><p>Regulamento do Uniforme CNE &#40;4MB&#41;</p></a></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
               <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a value="Scroll" id="scroll" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                  Actividades de Agrupamento
                  </a>
               </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="docs/planos/actividades_de_agrupamento_2014_2015.pdf"><img src="img/doc-pdf.png" alt="Download" class="img-rounded"><p>Plano de Actividades Agrupamento &#40;451KB&#41;</p></a></a></div>
                     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="docs/planos/actividades_de_Lobitos.pdf"><img src="img/doc-pdf.png" alt="Download" class="img-rounded"><p>Plano de Actividades 1&ordf; Sec&ccedil;&atilde;o &#40;440KB&#41;</p></a></a></div>
                     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="docs/planos/actividades_de_exploradores.pdf"><img src="img/doc-pdf.png" alt="Download" class="img-rounded"><p>Plano de Actividades 2&ordf; Sec&ccedil;&atilde;o &#40;202KB&#41;</p></a></a></div></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="docs/planos/actividades_de_Pioneiros.pdf"><img src="img/doc-pdf.png" alt="Download" class="img-rounded"><p>Plano de Actividades 3&ordf; Sec&ccedil;&atilde;o &#40;443KB&#41;</p></a></a></div>
                     <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                     <div class="col-md-4"></div></div>
                  </div>
               </div>


         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
               <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a value="Scroll" id="scroll" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFwor">
                  Cancioneiro 358
                  </a>
               </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseFwor" class="panel-collapse collapse">
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-4"></a></div>
                     <div class="col-md-4"><p>Cancioneiro = 1 Escuta</p><p>Encomendas para geral@agr358.cne-escutismo.pt</p><p>Entrege em mão na sede do 358</p></div>
                     <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

and the folowing aditional js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#scroll').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: '+=400'
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

for some reason the first collapse block works on scrolling down the page, but the others dont trigger the js.

What am i doing wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: ids should be unique...

Comment: so i should setup multiple istances of the same code in the .js to handle the several id's?

Comment: @willier you should not use an id, you should use a class instead - see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IDs in html [must be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2). You need to do `class='scroll'` instead of ID and then use `$(".scroll")`

Comment: Thank you, its working as i wanted.
Will accept awnser within when the time limit expires

Comment: @willier this answer is posted as a community wiki - feel free to edit it with more details on how you fixed your problem if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

ID must be unique. Change your a tags id property (id="scroll") to class (class="scroll") it should be work

and change your selector **$('#scroll')** to **$('.scroll')**